# USB Devices not usable when connected via thunderbolt in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, audio, debian, thunderbolt

I have Focal XS speakers (DAC via USB) connected to my monitors USB hub. The monitor is then connected to the laptop via thunderbolt 3 (USB-C). However, I cannot use any of the devices connected to the USB hub in the monitor. The speakers are detected, but does not show up as a output source.

If I connect a Macbook Pro in exactly the same way it works. If I connect the speakers USB cable directly to the laptop it also works.

Looking though dmesg I can see that Linux picks up and identifies something connected via USB:

```
# sudo dmesg | grep -E '(1-4.1|focal)' 
[    3.727499] hub 1-4:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.727516] hub 1-4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    4.097914] usb 1-4.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    4.208213] usb 1-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=08bb, idProduct=2704, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    4.208219] usb 1-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.208222] usb 1-4.1: Product: FOCAL XS        
[    4.208226] usb 1-4.1: Manufacturer: DAC FOR USB                     
[    4.214183] input: DAC FOR USB                      FOCAL XS         as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1:1.2/0003:08BB:2704.0004/input/input15
```

However it does not show up in /proc/asound/cards, pavucontrol or any other tool. It does not show up as an input source either.

```
# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xe8248000 irq 159
```

It does not show up in /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices, but I'm not sure if it's supposed to?

### Thoubleshooting so far

- Turned off Secure Boot to eliminate any issues with signed modules, but no difference. (Got a Lockdown: Loading of unsigned modules is restricted when it's on, turning it off only get rid of that log entry)
- Plugged various devices into the USB hub, like keyboard, none of them works. Keyboard does not even show up in dmesg at all.
- Pavucontrol, GNOME Control Panel and similar apps does not show any trace of the speakers.
- Reboot

### Info on hardware/software

- Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad T480s
- Speakers: [Focal XS 2.1](https://www.focal.com/en/home-audio/multimedia-and-wireless/focal-xs-21/focal-xs-21)
- Monitor: [Samsung C34J791](https://www.samsung.com/uk/monitors/curved-cf791/)
- Debian 10, stock kernel (4.19) that comes with Debian
- Secure Boot is off (for troubleshooting this)
- i3wm

Ideas?